# Validating an input based on the result of another input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I am building a registration form that needs validation. There are three input fields (not required in default) and a checkbox (has values yes and no). I want the checkbox to be required and if it's checked, those three input fields will be required, else they won't be required.

Now I can set it to be required when the checkbox value is *yes*, but when I select value *no*  for the checkbox, the three input fields are still required.

```js
var switchStatus = false;
if ($("#hidInd").val() == "") {
  $("#ind").prop("required", true);
  $("#first").prop("required", true);
  $("#second").prop("required", true);
  $("#third").prop("required", true);
}
$("#ind").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#hidInd").val("Y");
    $("#ind").prop("required", true);
    $("#first").prop("required", true);
    $("#second").prop("required", true);
    $("#third").prop("required", true);
  } else {
    switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#hidInd").val("N");
    $("#ind").prop("required", false);
    $("#first").val("");
    $("#second").val("");
    $("#third").val("");
    $("#first").prop("required", false);
    $("#second").prop("required", false);
    $("#third").prop("required", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery 3.3.1 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>

  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label for="DataOfficerInd" class="form-label">Please choose yes or no <i class="fa-solid fa-star-of-life required-field fa-xs"></i></label>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" id="hidInd" name="hidInd" value="" />
      <div class="d-inline-block mt-1 me-1">No</div>
      <div class="form-check form-switch d-inline-block form-switch-md">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="DataOfficer_ind" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <label for="ind" class="form-check-label mt-1 ms-1">Yes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Correct!</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please checked the swithch
    </div>
  </div>
  <h6>Please enter 3 username:</h6>
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label for="first" class="form-label">First Choice </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first">
    <div class="valid-feedback">Correct!</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill in the first choice.</div>
    <label for="second" class="form-label">Second Choice </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="second">
    <div class="valid-feedback">Correct!</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill in the second choice.</div>
    <label for="third" class="form-label">Third Choice </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="third">
    <div class="valid-feedback">Correct!</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill in the last choice.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#ind").on('change', ...` - you do not have an element with the id `ind`.

Comment: As @CBroe pointed, `id="DataOfficer_ind"` should be `id="ind"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the selector of the checkbox:

```js
var switchStatus = false;
if ($("#hidInd").val() == "") {
  $("#ind").prop("required", true);
  $("#first").prop("required", true);
  $("#second").prop("required", true);
  $("#third").prop("required", true);
}
$("#DataOfficer_ind").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#hidInd").val("Y");
    $("#ind").prop("required", true);
    $("#first").prop("required", true);
    $("#second").prop("required", true);
    $("#third").prop("required", true);
  } else {
    switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#hidInd").val("N");
    $("#ind").prop("required", false);
    $("#first").val("");
    $("#second").val("");
    $("#third").val("");
    $("#first").prop("required", false);
    $("#second").prop("required", false);
    $("#third").prop("required", false);
  }
});
```